# symfony 2.2.1 url rewrite issue

Tags: symfony, url-rewriting

Symfony 2.2.0 comes with the following default .htaccess inside /web/ directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
    #    RewriteBase /
    #</IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

My project layout is as follows:

```
/var/www/html/research/jba/php/
                              /src/
                              /web/
                                   .htaccess
                                   app.php
```

In /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@jba-research.jp
 ServerName www.jba-research.jp
 ServerAlias www.jba-research.jp
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/research/jba/php/web
 ErrorLog logs/www.jba-research.jp-error_log
 CustomLog logs/www.jba-research.jp-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/html/research/jba/php/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I could access login page like below:

```
https://www.jba-research.jp/jba/php/web/app.php/login
```

Now what I want is to access my login page as follows:

```
https://www.jba-research.jp/login
```

So I upgraded to symfony 2.2.1 which comes with the following new .htaccess file by default:

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# startpage (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewritting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the startpage because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # The following rewrites all other queries to the front controller. The
    # condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual
    # hosting, the base path will be prepended to allow proper resolution of the
    # app.php file; it will work in non-aliased environments as well, providing
    # a safe, one-size fits all solution.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
    # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
    # the startpage to the front controller explicitly so that the website
    # and the generated links can still be used.
    RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Now if I access

```
https://www.jba-research.jp/jba/php/web/app.php/login
```

it is redirected to

```
https://www.jba-research.jp/login
```

but Apache returns "not found" error.

So can someone help me solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run the application on *domain.tld/subfolder1/subfolder2/*

Add `RewriteBase` to your .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /subfolder1/subfolder2
```

For assets to work correctly you might need to configure the base url setting:

```
framework:
    #..
    templating:      
        engines: ['twig']
        assets_base_urls: http://domain.tld/subfolder1/subfolder2/
```

Comment: I checked your answer as correct, but what I did was a little different: First) In httpd.conf, created 'Alias /app "/var/www/html/research/jba/php/web"' Second) Inserted 'RewriteBase /app' in default symfony .htaccess file. And everything worked including static files (Login page accessed as app/login).